# Close all ng-bootstrap modals on logout

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

If the user session times out then he is redirected to the login page.

**Problem:** If they have a modal open then it remains open when the user is redirected.

What is a good centralized way to close any active modal upon some event (session timeout) using `ng-bootstrap` that doesn't involve putting code in every modal (or base class) or wrapping the `NgbModal` service?

I am using `Angular 4`, `Bootstrap 4`, and `ng-bootstrap`.

Comment: It appears NgbModalStack no longer includes `dismissAll()` its an open issue on their git awaiting a PR. Hopefully this is supported in the near future https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/643 If its ever supported you can hook in to a router change event

Answer (score 3):

You can import `import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` then define this in your logout component's constructor  `constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}` and finally use `this.modalService.dismissAll();` after your logut api call or session expire.

Comment: Is it working? I got Property 'dismissAll' does not exist on type 'NgbActiveModal' error.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal) { }
LogOut(){this.modalService.dismissAll();}
```